# Create actor on any unspecified/random node in cluster

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

It is possible to [programmatically create an actor on a remote node, if you specify the exact node](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.1/scala/remoting.html#Programmatic_Remote_Deployment).

However, I would like to simply ask the actor system to create an actor on a random, or perhaps the least utilised node.

Is it possible to create an actor on any remote node given an optional node role?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Akka 2.3 you should use [Cluster Aware Routers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.1/scala/cluster-usage.html#Cluster_Aware_Routers)

> All routers can be made aware of member nodes in the cluster, i.e. deploying new routees or looking up routees on nodes in the cluster.

So you can use RnadomPool, RoundRobinPool or BalancingPool router in your case.

See also [Remote Deployed Routees](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.1/scala/routing.html#Remote_Deployed_Routees).