# Akka actor creation with service dependencies on a random node in a cluster

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

This relates to [Create actor on any unspecified/random node in cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22802740/create-actor-on-any-unspecified-random-node-in-cluster).

I am new to akka. I looking at using akka 2.3.12 but could use latest 2.4 milestone. I would like to achieve the following:

- Create an actor (transparently) on a node with the least load in the cluster
- The actor has dependencies to a number of services
- The actor is created on demand, i.e. I don't want to create x number of actors on start-up.
- Any node can create an actor
- More than one actor can be created on a node

As far as I found out I need to create an adaptive (pool) cluster aware router on each node.

I am not sure what the config would look like. The documentation is somewhat confusing. Is the following correct or on the right track?

1)

```
akka.actor.deployment {
 /myService/myRouter {
   router = adaptive
   metrics-selector = mix
   cluster {
     enabled = on
     max-nr-of-instances-per-node = 1
     allow-local-routees = on
     } 
   }
 }
```

or 2)

```
akka.actor.deployment {
 /myService/myRouter = {
   router = adaptive
   metrics-selector = mix
   routees.paths = ["/user/worker”]
   cluster {
     enabled = on
     allow-local-routees = on
   }
  }
 }
```

or 3 (combination of 1 & 2):

```
akka.actor.deployment {
 /myService/myRouter = {
   router = adaptive
   metrics-selector = mix
   routees.paths = ["/user/worker”]
   cluster {
     enabled = on
     allow-local-routees = on
     max-nr-of-instances-per-node = 1
   }
  }
 }
```

Would a cluster config - similar to 1-3 - be enough to achieve above outlined goals? 
Does **max-nr-of-instances-per-node** refer to the number of routers on each node or the number of workers to be created on each node?

In regards to actor deployment and its dependencies

- Is the actor instantiated on one node and then deployed to a target node or is the actor instantiated on the target node?
- If the former is the case then the dependency injecting services is not correct. Should those services really be actors that are created on each node instead?
- What does this mean for supervision? Is the actor's supervisor local or remote?

I hope the information provided is clear. Any pointers are very much appreciated. Thank you.